# Is storing calculated values in database a bad idea?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

Let's say I'm working on an online store project. So, I'm gonna have to create a table called 'Product' in my database. Say I also want users to be able to 'like' my products. That requires me to create another table called 'ProductLike' to store users' IDs alongside the ID of the product they like (a junction table).

**The main scenario:** Every time when a user sends a request to my website to get a product page, I'm gonna have to recalculate the number of likes that product has.

**My question is:** So, I know the standard approach is not to store 'Calculated values' in the database (normalization). But what about cases like this? (I mean cases in which it might be expensive to calculate something). For instance in the example above, isn't it better to have a column named 'NumberOfLikes' in the 'Product' table to store the calculated number of the product likes for fast retrieval?

Comment: Product table could itself have a column: likeCount. You could update this, whenever user likes/unlikes a particular product. While answering this, I felt that a graph database would be proper to design a solution.. You could also have a table with 2 columns: userid, likedProductId. Add a row whenever user likes a product and remove whenever...

Comment: What value is being calculated?  What does a "request" have to do with a "like"?

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Comment: This is too broad, but nevertheles is also a faq. Always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is storing counts of database record redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512402/is-storing-counts-of-database-record-redundant)

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

> isn't it better to have a column named 'NumberOfLikes' in the 'Product' table to store the calculated number of the product likes?

IMHO, the direct answer to this question is "No, unless you have a real performance problem due to the counting of likes".

If you do have a performance problem, and you've identified its source as the count of likes, Then you might want to consider adding a `LikesCount` column to the `products` table. If you do add such a column, please note you are going to have to update it on every change to the `ProductLike` table - delete, update and insert.
This means you are going to have to write a trigger for this table to handle all these cases, but it shouldn't be too hard since you can do everything in a single trigger - something like this:

```
create trigger ProductLikeChaneged on ProductLike 
for insert, update, delete
as

    update p
    set LikesCount = (select count(*) from ProductLike as pl where pl.productId = p.Id)
    from product as p
    where exists
    (
        select 1 from inserted as i where p.id = i.productId
    )
    or exists
    (
        select 1 from deleted as d where p.id = d.productId
    )
```

**Original version**
Based on your description, "calculating" the number of likes for a product is simply a count of rows in the `ProductLike` table where the product id is the id of the product you are currently displaying to the user.
This can be done very fast, especially if the `ProductLike` table clustered index is `ProductId` and then `UserId`, thus allowing SQL Server to use clustered index seek and not a table scan.

Basically, your `ProductLike` table should look like this:

```
 Create table ProductLike
 (
     ProductId int,
     UserId int,
     Constraint PK_ProductLike PRIMARY KEY (ProductId, UserId)
 )
```

Note that by default, SQL Server will use the primary key as the clustered index of the table.

Then your select statement for the product page can be something like this:

```
select Name, Description, -- Other product related details
       (select count(*) 
        from productLike as pl 
        where pl.ProductId = p.Id) as likeCount
from product as p
```

Answer (score 4):

By "calculated" value, I suspect you mean an accumulation of the number of requests.

The simplest approach in terms of database design and maintenance is to store each request as a row in a table and to summarize when needed.  This has certain nice features:

- A user can "unrequest" or "unlike" quite easily.
- Inserts are (typically) at the "end" of the table, minimizing fragmentation and speeding inserts.  Note:  This can result in contention for the last page if multiple threads are writing at the same time.
- Counts can be flexible, limited to a particular date range or type of user for instance.
- The data is drill-downable.  That is, for a given count you know exactly what produced it.

Summarization is often very reasonable, if you have the right indexes and partitions on the data.

That said, such summarization does not meet all needs.  A traditional approach is to use a trigger to maintain summary tables -- adding lots of complexity for maintenance (you need insert, delete, and update triggers).  I think @daniherrera's answer gives guidance on the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

For real life they are real solutions. You should to materialize this field and denormalize database to keep performance. Do you have serveral options to keep this field uptodate:

- [Materialized views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/materialized-view).
- [Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
- [Store procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Disclaimer: Your question is a primary opinion-based, I guess will be closed in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Number of product liked by user can be fetched by UserProductLike table, where userid is id of your user.

[image]

Comment: It's obvious, it wasn't my question