# MS ACCESS: VBA too fast leading to field updating only if Toggle Breakpoint in code, need timer?

Tags: vba, ms-access, delay, wait, pause

I am currently doing a Purchase Order "software" under Access and I am having issue with calculating the amount after a item quantity (qty) update.

When I have Toggle breakpoints in my VBA code on the "after update" event, after updating qty = 5 and going through the lines of code, I have the parent text field correctly updated from the subform one (which is the sum of the 'Total Price' fields).
The code contains a Refresh in order to add the right value rather than the old one:

[image: PB1]

[image: PB2]

.

.

**However, when I remove the toggle breakpoint, I think that the VBA code does not have enough time fully process the refresh command, which update the parent text field with the wrong (old) value.**

This issue leads to have a discrepancy between the actual subform calculated total, and the value added to the parent table (here I removed the toggle breakpoint, and added 1 on the second line item, but the calculation gave a 250 rather than a 251):

[image: PB3]

When I look at the values in the code, when the breakpoint is on the updating line, you can see that the value of the field is the right one, but the 'watch' field shows the old value:

[image: PB4]

.

.

**Do you guys have a solution to make sure all the fields are updated before going to the next line?**

I was thinking using some sort of delay, or an "application wait until processing done" type of command but I cannot find anything that is actually working;

Let me know,

Cheers!

***EDIT 1:***

- The "Expected Total Cost" is bound to a table field called "curPOExpectedTotalCost", which is why I use VBA code to populate the data into its dedicated textbox (called "txtcurPOExpectedTotalCost").
- The main goal is simply to have this bound field being correctly updated; I want to be able to change the qty or the unit price and automatically populate the right total PO price into "Expected Total Cost" which is bound to a table; the issue is that it works well when I am running each lines one by one using the breakpoints in my code, but does not work when I remove them; this tells me it is probably too fast, hence a way of delaying the next command or a command to wait for processing to be done.

***EDIT 2:***

I found a workaround, but it seems overpowered for this simple task I was trying to achieve; good side is that it removes the middle man (the subform textbox that sum all the total prices):

I open a recordset and iterate a variable until I can populate the result into the dedicated "Expected Total Cost" bound textbox:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand (acCmdRefresh)

Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "SELECT numPONumberAndRevID, numPOContentQtyOrdered, numPOContentPrice FROM tblPOSCONTENT WHERE numPONumberAndRevID = " & Nz(Me.Parent.MasterPOID.Value)
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)

Do While Not RS.EOF
    ExpectedCalculatedCost = ExpectedCalculatedCost + RS("numPOContentQtyOrdered") * RS("numPOContentPrice")
    RS.MoveNext
Loop
RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing

Me.Parent.txtcurPOExpectedTotalCost.Value = ExpectedCalculatedCost
```

Comment: Please backup and advise on your overall goal. What are you trying to do? If you need to validate user entries before record edit, you should use [BeforeUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.beforeupdate-event) event.

Comment: Ideally, totals and balances are not saved but are calculated from raw transaction records when needed.

Answer (score 1):

We could arrange in a simple way.

We name the detail input subform control as `sfrmDetail`, the main total control can be assigned with a `.ControlSource` like:

```
Me.txtcurPOExpectedTotalCost.ControlSource="=[sfrmDetail].[Form].[txtSubFormExpectedTotalCost]"
```

When **txtnumPOContentQtyOrdered** updates, your main form changes instanteneously without any VBA code.

In the subform, say sfrmDetail, that will be embedded in the main form as subformcontrol sfrmDetail (yes with the same name), we assign a .ControlSouce=Sum(Qty*UnitPrice) for the control `txtSubFormExpectedTotalCost`, at the footer of the subform.

---

**Solution II**:

As @June7 pointed out in comments, the Total cost, that can be calculated dynamically, should be better only for display only (form input display, report printing, but not saved in disk).

OK, now we want at any cost to stock in field tblMain.curPOExpectedTotalCost the total cost with a slight data redundancy, so in the main form we have `Me.txtcurPOExpectedTotalCost.ControlSource="curPOExpectedTotalCost"`

In the subform sfrmDetail, we can update with:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
    
Private Sub txtnumPOContentQtyOrdered_AfterUpdate()
  Me.Recalc
  Me.Parent.txtcurPOExpectedTotalCost.Value = Me.txtSubformExpectedTotalCost.Value
End Sub
```

`Me.Recalc()` updates all calculated fields of sfrmDetail before we change the target main table field.

[image]

Please consult also [Is storing counts of database record redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512402/is-storing-counts-of-database-record-redundant) for data redundancy.

Comment: But isn't that VBA code you show? Instead of VBA code, put expression directly in textbox ControlSource property: `=[sfrmDetail].[Form].[txtSubFormExpectedTotalCost]`. Textbox in subform would have expression:: `=Sum(Qty*Price)`.

Comment: Yes you can do it in design mode for the main form.

Comment: The issue is that the "Expected Total Cost" is bound to a table field called "curPOExpectedTotalCost"; so I was trying to update it, but I unfortunately cannot have the textbox control source being " curPOExpectedTotalCost =[sfrmDetail].[Form].[txtSubFormExpectedTotalCost]" ; Do you have another way that works with a bound textbox ?

Comment: So you have two tables, say tblMain and tblDetail. So the field curPOExpectedTotalCost is in the tblMain, sure not in tblDetail ?

Comment: I think that stock curPOExpectedTotalCost  value as a separate table field, that can be calculated dynamically, is a data redundance. Inconsistency will occur if you modify it directly opening the table, without using form interface. This value should be better only for display only (not saved).